# NGINX: Cannot config nginx to handle redirect from HTTP to HTTPS redirect not working

Tags: nginx, https, http, 301-redirect

I have try to config nginx: /etc/nginx/nginx.conf

```
server {
    listen 80 default_server;
    listen [::]:80 default_server;
    server_name 10.0.0.10; #This is my private IP
    return 301 https://$server_name$request_uri;
    # OR return 301 https://$host$request_uri
}
```

But it cannot redirect from HTTP to HTTPS. Please help me on this.
Thanks.

Comment: Try: `return 301 https://$host$request_uri;`

Comment: I have already tried this but the direction still not working.

Comment: Ok, `$server_name` will not work as it will use an IP address and the secure server will not like that. Have you tried: `curl -I http://example.com`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the issue is the IP as server name. Try and edit your hosts file and add an entry for the IP. For example:

```
10.0.0.10 myserver.test
```

The edit the nginx configuration and change the server_name parameter to:

```
server_name myserver.test;
```

restart nginx or reload the configuration.

Comment: HTTPS needs to use SSL with HTTP protocol to build a secure and verified connection. It is heavily relies on the domain name. In case you are specifing the IP, it won't work as expected. You can use ` server_name _;` as your server name, but your client must have a valid DNS configuration, at least hosts file needs to know to which IP redirect your request.